# C++ and SDL: Problem with showing image?

Tags: c++, loading, sdl, bmp

For some reason SDL refuses to render an image. I don't see why and it's really bogging down my progress on a 2d game i'm developing. Everything is linked properly and such. Here's my code:

```
//main.cpp
#include "main.h"

void game::createWindow(const int SCREEN_W, const int SCREEN_H, const char* SCREEN_NAME)
{
 buffer = SDL_SetVideoMode(SCREEN_W, SCREEN_H, 0, NULL);
 SDL_WM_SetCaption(SCREEN_NAME, NULL);
}

void game::enterLoop()
{
 while(Running == true)
 {
  SDL_BlitSurface(zombie, NULL, buffer, NULL);
  SDL_Flip(buffer);

  while(SDL_PollEvent(&gameEvent))
  {
   if(gameEvent.type == SDL_QUIT)
   {
    Running = false;
   }
  }
 }
}

void game::loadContent()
{
 zombie = SDL_LoadBMP("zombie.bmp");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 game gameObj;

 SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
 gameObj.createWindow(960, 600, "uShootZombies");
 gameObj.loadContent();
 gameObj.enterLoop();

 SDL_Quit();

 return 0;
}

//main.h
#include <SDL.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class game
{
 public:
 void createWindow(const int SCREEN_W, const int SCREEN_H, const char* SCREEN_NAME);
 void enterLoop();
 void loadContent();

 game()
 {
  Running = true;
 }

 ~game()
 {
  SDL_FreeSurface(buffer);

  SDL_FreeSurface(background);
  SDL_FreeSurface(player);
  SDL_FreeSurface(zombie);
 }

 private:
 SDL_Surface* buffer;

 SDL_Surface* background;
 SDL_Surface* player;
 SDL_Surface* zombie;

 SDL_Event gameEvent;
 bool Running;
};NU
```

Comment: Have you checked if your surfaces are valid after loading?

Comment: I don't exactly error check as you can see. However I tried using very basic "int main-only" code that simply loaded a valid image and put it onto the screen. No luck there either. If you want to see what code I used, go to lazy foo's sdl tutorials and look at the first tutorial (that isn't the "setting up SDL" one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copied all of your code to use in code::blocks and it works fine.
Of course I was using my own .bmp file which I named "zombie.bmp"

Are you sure your .bmp file is ok?

Be aware that if you originally save it as a .jpeg file or something like that, then simply renamed it to .bmp, it won't work (And it won't throw an error either)

It must be originally saved as a bmp.

That is all I can think of.

Comment: Also if you are using lazy foo's tutorials, you will learn about setting up SDL_image (http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/) which will give you more freedom over which file extension you use anyway.

Comment: You were right. It worked. I dunno why it wasn't a bmp even though I remember saving it as one. Sometimes those little things are the answer huh?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Sour Lemon has already solved your problem, but I still thought it would be worth pointing out that the above code doesn't perform any checks to make sure that your zombie image was actually loaded correctly.

You should be doing something like this:

```
void game::loadContent()
{
    zombie = SDL_LoadBMP("zombie.bmp");
    if (zombie == NULL) {
        ReportError(SDL_GetError());
    }
}
```